# Fresh Ubuntu 18 install: Blank Purple Screen after login

Tags: system-installation

I just installed Ubuntu 18 on a laptop.  It seemed to go well.  After the installation completed, the laptop rebooted, I got to the login prompt, I logged in, then I get a blank purple screen with no taskbars, or toolbars. I do have a mouse and mouse pointer, and I can move the mouse pointer around the screen, but I can't do anything else.  What should I do?

Comment: Please post hardware specifications. And why 18.04 and not 20.04?

Comment: Ubuntu 18?    Ubuntu desktop and server releases have a *yy.mm* format, and whilst specialist snap based releases like Ubuntu Core 18 for IoT appliances do use a *yy* format there are none titled just Ubuntu 18.  Please clarify your release as there is no Ubuntu 18.  Are you talking about Ubuntu Core 18?   *Whilst you can use the snap only 18 as a desktop, that was not the intended purpose so you'd be better using a 18.04 or 20.04 system over 18*